# Android RemoteControlClient Bitmap Scaling

Tags: android, bitmap, scale

I have successfully included `RemoteControlClient` in my app.  However, I was wondering if there is any way to prevent the bitmaps thrown at it from scaling On all aspects.  I can do this in my activity, scaling the vertical, and preserving the aspect , but throwing the scaled bitmap to the client has no effect.  It always scales to square, filling the view.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, create a black (or transparent?) square bitmap background and center your album artwork or whatever it is on it... Then send a square image to RemoteControlClient.